# Is there any academic paper documented about firms' trade credit collection approach?

Tags: reference-request, consumer-credit

I am looking for some papers that documented some [trade credit](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/10/3/661/1635350?login=true) collection approaches, especially when the market becomes more competitive. In another word, what should the managers do to improve the efficiency in collecting the account receivable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hit from [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22trade%20credit%20collection%22&btnG=) (had to go to the bottom of page 1 for this one!) is

[Macro-Economic Growth,Enterprise Competitive Status and Trade Credit Policy](https://en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTotal-CMYJ201406020.htm)

Abstract:

> This paper investigates the effect of macro- economic growth and enterprise competitive status on trade credit policy from suppliers with trade credit's perspective,and the moderate effect of industry characteristics. The study indicates that: The higher the competitive status,the shorter the trade credit collection period to downstream enterprises,while this relation is not obvious among enterprises in less concentrated industry; When macro- economic grows fast,regardless howconcentrated industries that enterprises are located in,enterprises with higher competitive status are more prone to reduce the account receivable collective period; With further considering industry characteristic,the effect of macro- economic growth and competitive status of enterprises on trade credit policy shows significant difference in the quadrant formed by different industry prosperity and concentration.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I cannot download this paper, could you please help me the DOI link of this paper ,please ?

Comment: @BeautifulMindset Now that I tried, I couldn't either. Sorry! Hopefully you'll find a similar one in the Scholar results.